# Samba share cannot be accessed from windows PC on a different subnet

Tags: linux, windows, samba, subnet, share

I have set up a linux (CentOS 5) box with a samba share on a large network.  The network has 2 subnets, one on 192.168/16 and one on 172.18/16.  The server lives on the 172.18/16 subnet.

I can ping the server from client Windows XP workstations on both subnets.

When I open the list of workgroup computers, I can see my new server in the list of Workgroup machines from Windows XP client workstations on both subnets.

However, I can access the share from workstations on the same subnet, but when I try to access it from workstations on the other subnet I get a message saying either:

> o Windows cannot find the specified resource, or
>   o Access to this network resource has been disallowed.

I have had a look at the smb.conf file, and there is nothing obvious that would be causing a problem.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Rik

Comment: Does it work if you access it from a vlient on the same subnet?

Comment: It does work when I try to access the share from clients on the same subnet.  I cannot access the share from clients on the other subnet, despite the fact that these clients *are* able to ping the server in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be DNS (which is fairly embarassing to be honest).  The 172.18/16 half of the network was fine, but the 192.168/16 half of the network couldn't get to the share because it couldn't resolve the name of the server.  When we tried going in via the IP address it worked fine.